Can Antimagic Field negate Demilich's Damage Reduction?

Damage Reduction (Su): A demilich loses any previous damage reduction and instead has damage reduction 15/Epic and bludgeoning (15
points of damage is subtracted from all melee attacks unless the weapon used is both an epic and a bludgeoning
weapon). Vorpal weapons, no matter their enhancement bonus, ignore this damage reduction but do only half damage
to a demilich (demiliches cannot be beheaded).

Since Demilich's Damage Reduction is a Supernatural Ability, then I guess it can be suppressed by an Antimagic Field.

Supernatural Abilities (Su): Supernatural abilities are magical but not spell-like. Supernatural
abilities are not subject to spell resistance and do not function in areas where magic is suppressed or negated
(such as an antimagic field). A supernatural ability's effect cannot be dispelled and is not subject to
counterspells. See the table below for a summary of the types of special abilities.

And it seems for some reasons a demilich does not have skeleton template, which means this is the only DR they can get. Negating it would cause it become vulnerable to all types of physical damage. I see this also applies to vampire and lich.
Just want to confirm if this is actually the case, that all these creatures can actually be harmed by all kinds of weapons when inside an Antimagic Field.

Correct
That’s precisely what the “Su” tag on the ability is for, to tell you that it’s vulnerable to an antimagic field like this.
Note that the lich’s immunities are tagged “Ex,” that is, extraordinary, which means they are not removed by antimagic field. Moreover, note that the lich automatically reappearing 1d10 days later is also not marked “Su”—it’s not clearly marked at all, to be fair, which is an ambiguous state generally, but if nothing else, there is nothing clearly indicating that an antimagic field stops that, either. So while it is true that the lich loses all damage reduction in an antimagic field, describing it as “vulnerable” might be overstating things somewhat. It still has extremely potent defenses. And antimagic fields are very small, making it difficult to keep someone in one.

https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lich.htm Lich's DR is marked as "SU" in here, though. Is there a different version of lich somewhere?

@TerryWindwalker No? I agreed that the the DR is Su and thus goes away in an antimagic field. I just point out that it has other defenses, like immunities to a bunch of things and the ability to reappear automatically 1d10 days after its destruction, which do not go away in an antimagic field.

No worries, I thought you were saying the DR being EX. I guess most creatures' DR are EX except for these exceptions (lich, demilich, vampire).

@TerryWindwalker It's sadly more complicated than that. See this question.

@HeyICanChan Interesting. But these creatures have their DR specified as SU so I guess there's no problem for them. Wondering if the DR X/magic (SU) and bludgeoning (EX) should be counted as 2 different entries of special abilities and be handled differently for some other creatures.

@TerryWindwalker Having DR X/Y and Z from one source is numerically the same as having DR X/Y from one source, and DR X/Z from the other source. So it would be more or less reasonable homerule to let your lich keep DR 15/bludgeoning in an AMF. RAW, the whole thing is negated... as well as it's flight and it's attacks, so... is it really that important?

@annoyingimp Wait, its fly ability is also negated? I thought it is an EX ability. Isn't that making demilich a meat bag for any melee character with AMF?

@TerryWindwalker No, the demilich’s 180-foot (perfect) flight speed is not supernatural. It doesn’t have a listed type, and for once “natural ability” probably is appropriate for that. I believe annoying imp misread the statement that the demilich template retains any supernatural flight the base creature already had, in addition to the demilich’s natural flight.

@TerryWindwalker Between it being a flying skull, it loosing every instance of non-magical flight during application of the template, and a statement from alter self saying "Physical qualities include ... mundane movement capabilities (... flight with wings, to a maximum speed of 120 feet for flying or 60 feet for nonflying movement)", I believe, I have a ground under my statement. Still, was surprised there seems to be no general rule on the matter. I have always assumed, alter self refers to that, actually non-existent, general rule.
